# How can an empty postgres RDS table have a size of 1.4GB?

Tags: postgresql

I am running a postgres RDS db on AWS. I deleted all rows in a table and vacuumed the table. However, I noticed that the table size is still 1.4GB. Any ideas why this might be the case? I tried refreshing the db connection as well as rebooting the database to no avail.

I ran `SELECT * FROM pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"schema_name"."table_name"'));` and got 1400MB as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187044/disk-space-unreleased-after-cleaning-up-rows-from-pg-table. I did run vacuum, but did not run VACUUM FULL. Hence I am facing this issue.

Followup: I ran `VACUUM FULL` and that resolved the issue. The table looks normal now.

Comment: If the table was empty or should be empty, you could have used truncate. That’s way faster and also returns all unused disk space